# PHP & WordPress - How can I have a function run after post meta updates to output to a JSON file?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using `save_post_{post_type}` hook to generate a JSON file with all the content of a custom post type.

```
add_action('save_post_book', 'updateBooks');

function updateBooks(){
    $url = site_url().'/wp-json/wp/v2/books?_embed=true/';
    $params = array( 'timeout' => 30, 'sslverify' => false );
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $params );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    file_put_contents($path.'/books.json', $body);
}
```

The problem is with ACF custom fields. I believe the hook runs before post meta updates. So the new values from the ACF fields are not sent to the JSON files.

**Solution**

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'updateJson', 20);

function updateJson($post_id){
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $url = site_url().'/wp-json/wp/v2/'.$post_type.'?_embed=true/';
    $params = array( 'timeout' => 30, 'sslverify' => false );
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url, $params );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    file_put_contents($path.'/'.$post_type.'.json', $body);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ACF hooks:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

You can specify the field or run in all of them

Comment: Nice. `acf/save_post` do the job.